# MVC: Can I post to a controller without using javascript/ajax/jquery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The problem is I want to change server side variables using a dropdownlist in a partial view.  You can't use scripts in partial views.

Is an html helper I can use to post a simple variable to a controller (like an int) when the user clicks an item in the dropdownlist (or bootstrap dropdown)?

Comment: so why you can't use jquery in your partial view? you can!

Comment: Don't you need to wrap any scripts in a section?

Answer (score 0):

You can use scripts in partial views, but I recommand you to put js/jquery scripts in the container page, not the partial itself

on index.cshtml:

```
    @Html.Partial("_LoadView")

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(document).on('change', '.target', function () {
                alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
                // Ajax call to controller
            }
}
</script>
```

on _LoadView.cshtml :

```
  <select class="target">
    <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make the assumption that you are thinking that you cannot use scripts in the partials because if a partial is used multiple times on a page the script is repeated.

You can circumvent this issue by putting your script inside an external file and loading it in the partial via a HTML Helper, which checks to see if it is already loaded and prevents it happening a second time.

In your partial:

```
@{Html.RegisterScript("~/Scripts/MyFile.js");}
```

And in your backend code (HtmlExtentions.cs)

```
namespace MyProj.Helpers
{
public static class HtmlExtentions
{
    public static IHtmlString RenderRegisteredScripts(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var ctx = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext;
        var registeredScripts = ctx.Items["_scripts_"] as Stack<string>;
        if (registeredScripts == null || registeredScripts.Count < 1)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var script in registeredScripts)
        {
            var scriptBuilder = new TagBuilder("script");
            scriptBuilder.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
            scriptBuilder.Attributes["src"] = script;
            sb.AppendLine(scriptBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        }
        return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }

    public static void RegisterScript(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string script)
    {
        var ctx = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext;
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var registeredScripts = ctx.Items["_scripts_"] as Stack<string>;
        if (registeredScripts == null)
        {
            registeredScripts = new Stack<string>();
            ctx.Items["_scripts_"] = registeredScripts;
        }
        var src = urlHelper.Content(script);
        if (!registeredScripts.Contains(src))
        {
            registeredScripts.Push(src);
        }
    }
}
}
```